# Is there a German word for “graffiti”?

Tags: single-word-request

Is there a verb form of “graffiti” in German? The closest I’ve found is “strichen,” though that’s not really what I’m looking for.

Comment: My primary association for "strichen" is "to prostitute oneself". Don't use that word.

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Where did you find this alleged verb of graffiti? "streichen" might be some translation of "to paint". Anyway, I'm for "sprayen". It's a spray, so what you do with it, might be "sprayen". A little bit more old-fashioned might be "malen". At the very least I would understand somebody saying that he is a "Graffiti malen".

Comment: The term used within the scene is supposedly "taggen".

Answer (score 12):

This is a contentious issue.

Those doing/making graffiti say mostly *sprühen* or *[sprayen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/sprayen)*. There are quite a few synonyms, especially within the 'scene'.

If the German target audience *is* that scene: orient your words on [Graffiti-Jargon](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graffiti-Jargon).

Those doing this are quite a different demographic from mainstream society. What some call (street-) art, others just call *Schmierereien*. The verb for that would then be *[schmieren](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/schmieren)*, *beschmieren*.

The fundamental difference between those words is opinion based (and then some).

*Schmieren* is clearly derogatory. *Sprayen* not understood by many on several levels of meaning, conservatism, old people, etc.

---

References for "Graffiti=Schmierereien":

https://www.polizei.sachsen.de/de/MI_2017_55383.htm
http://www.maz-online.de/Lokales/Potsdam/57-Strafanzeigen-gegen-Jugendliche-gestellt

---

For a glimpse of German usage and a clouded meaning pattern:

> [image]
>   Src: DWDS – [Graffiti, das](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Graffiti)

A proper translation for *to graffiti* would therefore have to be *sprühen*. This has in my opinion the least negative or positive connotation, and is therefore also less clear-cut.

As this is about a living language, you may also ask yourself about your own opinion whether *streetarten* might be the ahem, more fitting translation.

Comment: I think *schmieren* or *Schmiererei* has a certain difference in meaning when compared to *Graffiti*: The former generally refers to graffiti in arguably illegitimate places, as it is often seen in public space, whereas the latter can also mean the graphics style often used for graffiti as such.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Not wrong, but depends pretty much on demographic.Some can't see anything but *Schmierereien* regardless of painting surface. That is: even a framed and unshredded Banksy is a *Schmiererei* to them.

Comment: There are always some people who do not like or find no "access" to a given work. They may call Rembrandt's works "Schmierereien" and Goethe's works "Gefasel". Yet, I wouldn't list these words as possible translations for "painting" and "literature", respectively, "depending on the demographic". "Schmiererei" for "graffiti", on the other hand, *is* a somewhat legitimate (if derogatory) translation specifically in the context of graffiti being placed illegitimately.

Comment: -1 because Schmierereien is only the very negative connotation of a word which is not necessarily bad

Comment: Fat agreement. Maybe I'll add a disclaimer: "AH, but please, mh'äüöhm, well, it's prolly like, uh, dangerous and lowering your IQ by at least -1, because, so y'all should have forgotten better already the very unwanted word of *Schmierereien* even exists, hmhm, yesyes, or might be used, as there is önly öne cörrect word in each and every case, anyway, this is BIG, so listen: this is only the very negative connotation of a word which is not necessarily bad."

Answer (score 8):

'Graffiti' is an Italian loan-word in both English and German (from *graffiato*). It can be used in both languages and is a cognate in its noun form.

In common parlance, I'm not aware of a recognized verb form. You might consider phrasing your sentence such that an alternative verb can be used such as:
"[etwas] mit Graffiti besprühen".

Answer (score 1):

The word in German for a piece is called "graffito". Graff comes from the united states and as such even we in Europe use the same words the americans used to (or still do) in the culture.

Aside from this most graffiti writers refer to each other as "writers".

- Graffiti writer from Amsterdam

Comment: Does this answer if there is a verb form of "graffiti" in German?

Comment: Yes. When a writer is making a piece of graffiti, he is "writing" or "schreiben".